# Homogeneous space of the unitary group U(n)

Tags: unitary-matrices

Consider the unitary group $U(2^n)$ and let $G$ be the subgroup isomorphic to $U(2^{n-1})$ embedded as:
\begin{pmatrix}
U & 0\\
0 & U
\end{pmatrix}
where $U \in U(2^{n-1})$ (the same matrix in both blocks). How to describe the homogeneous space $U(2^n) / G$? Do we get a Stiefel manifold as in the case of embedding:
\begin{pmatrix}
Id & 0\\
0 & U
\end{pmatrix}

> 

Comment: What's $U$? You have $G \cong U \times U$.